# Debugging a SIGABRT error in a program with 2D array

Tags: c

I am trying to debug a text editor program where I create a 2D array that doubles its size every time there's a new input from a file. Valgrind returns this:

```
==1454== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
==1454==    at 0x48A518B: raise (raise.c:51)
==1454==    by 0x4884858: abort (abort.c:79)
==1454==    by 0x48EF3ED: __libc_message (libc_fatal.c:155)
==1454==    by 0x49919B9: __fortify_fail (fortify_fail.c:26)
==1454==    by 0x4991985: __stack_chk_fail (stack_chk_fail.c:24)
==1454==    by 0x10980C: main (in /home/utente/Desktop/main)
```

here's my main where I call a fun to reallocate the array

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    cmd istruction;
    char **Array = {0};
    fp=fopen("prova.txt", "rt");
    int dim=30;
 Array = Create2D(H);
 istruction=GetOrder(fp);
        while (dim<variable) {
            Array = Reallocation2D(Array,dim);
            dim=dim*2;
        }
        doing stuff...
        }
    }

    free2D(Array, dim);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

the create array and reallocation2D are

```
char ** Create2D(ssize_t Strings)
{
    char **a = {0};
    a = calloc(Strings, sizeof(char *));
    return a;
}
```

```
char ** Reallocation2D(char ** a, size_t dim){
    int i;
    char **b = {0};
    b = calloc(dim*2, sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<dim*2; i++)
    {
        b[i] = calloc(1024, 1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
        if(a[i]) strcpy(b[i],a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<dim; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]) free(a[i]);
    }

    free(a);

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow ?

Comment: you are at the right place because very probably you have a ... stack overflow ^^ Being in *main* perhaps you use a too large variable length arrays ?

Comment: Post the code if you want help

Comment: Done it, maybe is how I use the pointers

Comment: how much is *H* in `Array = Create2D(H);` ?

Comment: the number H is 30

Comment: in `GetOrder(fp);` *fp* is not initialized, what *GetOrder* does ?

Comment: Yea I forgot to post it, the fact is that the program runs, and the output is correct but there's an abort and execution killed

Comment: getorder takes the line and analyse the parameters for the text editor

Comment: @bruno: the OP uses Valgrind already, he posted the output.

Comment: There is still code missing. What is `H`. What is `GetOrder`. What is "doing stuff..."

Comment: yes @4386427 and what *variable* values etc, this is why I finally voted to close after several attempts to help through remarks in the answer ...

Comment: Nothing in the posted code indicates a stack overflow. Why do you think that the problem is in this part of the code?

Answer (score 3):

Without the code, one can only try and analyse valgrind's output:

The problem seems to occur in the `main()` function where you have a **stack overflow**. Do you call a function that define a very large automatic array? Or do you define such an array in `main()` itself?

From the posted code, here are some problems:

- the initial call to `Create2D` allocates space for a `H` pointers, but you initialize `dim` to `30`. `H` is not defined, is it a `#define` for `30`?
- where does `variable` get set?
- why do you reallocate the `char` arrays instead of copying them?
- you allocate lines with a size of `1024` bytes. This may use much more code memory than the file on disk an would still not suffice if a line in the file os longer than that.
- why not use `realloc()` in `Reallocation2D` and initialize the newly allocated part to `NULL` pointers?
- you should test for allocation failure and report it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217805/discussion-on-answer-by-chqrlie-debugging-a-sigabrt-error-in-a-program-with-2d-a).